# Output Caching Not Working in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I can't seem to get my ASP.net webforms site to cache CSS files. In IIS I configure Output Caching following the instructions at the link below. But when I monitor Network activity in F12 tools, there is no sign of caching.

Is there something simple I am missing ?

[Link to instructions on configuring Output Cache in IIS](https://codewala.net/2014/07/01/leverage-output-caching-with-iis7-x-and-iis8-x/)

Answer (score 1):

After examining Network activity some more, I noticed a lot of Result values of '403'. I am using JQuery UI libraries and the standard JQuery CSS base file was trying to import all known JQuery UI CSS files (i.e accordion, date picker). I didn't have these in my project. After removing unused imports, I no longer have any '403' results. And also that fixed the caching problem. The CSS files are now being cached.